# mysql: CONVERT() function not working to bytes from GROUP_CONCAT() into VARCHAR

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql's `GROUP_CONCAT()` for one of my query. But I am getting data in bytes.
To convert the bytes into `VARCHAR` I used the `CONVERT()` function.
But I dont see any difference even after that. I am still getting data in bytes.

Below is what I have tried:

```
CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT((T1.CASE NODE_ID WHEN 103 THEN CONCAT(T1.CUSTOMER_ATTRIBUTE,'~',T2.DISPLAY_TEXT) ELSE NULL END)) USING LATIN1)AS HEADER,
```

but I am getting the output as:

```
HEADER
----------
Name [4B]
```

Help needed.

Thanks.

Comment: What client do you use? Try to use mysql client - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html.

Comment: Well I am using SQLYog and TOAD for MYSQL... In SQLYog I get the result as mentioned above [4B] while in TOAD I get the result as `(Excluded)`. And when I click on it, the query is fired again to give me the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(your_column)) this will give as the string as output

cheers..

Comment: Tried this.. No change.. Same result!

Answer (score 0):

This is because different types are passed into CONCAT function. MySQL converts them into appropriate type, in your case it is BLOB or something else.

The solution is to convert all non-string types to string, or just convert result of CONCAT function to string once. For example -

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(id, '~', column1, column2) AS CHAR)
```